# (Node.js+express+MongoDB), how to OPTIMIZE an frequently-used variable?

Tags: javascript, optimization, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm building a dynamic website using Node.js+express+MongoDB

And there're some numbers that exist in almost every page,(like the amount of users/pages/articles of the site, showing in the footer)

since they exist in every page, I think they will slow down my site, if I call it every time like before rendering just like an not such useful variable.

Am I right?

1.if so, how to optimize this prob? use dynamicHelpers? how to do that? is there any examples?

2.which one is better? put them in DB or in CONFIG file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using mongo, you can put all of these keys inside an index.

If your doc looks like this:

```
doc = {
    'users': 50,
    'page': 10,
    'articles': 20
}
```

simply do:

```
db.foo.ensureIndex( {
    'users': 1,
    'page': 1,
    'articles': 1
})
```

Then make sure you only return these keys.

If these are in an index, Mongo will read these values directly from memory and not from disk.

If you want to query this by something like an _id instead, simply add the _id as the first part of the index, and include the rest of the items in the index.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields#RetrievingaSubsetofFields-CoveredIndexes

Answer (score 0):

You should cache these values in memory with a short timeout; on each request, check how long ago your application cached these values and if the timeout has expired, re-query.